# automatically expand selection to a block of lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

trying to add html tags to a textarea value
for example - pls select `dolor sit` block of two lines - and click the button
selection is converted to html

question - is there a way to do the same without make a selection manually
just by placing the carret into a block of lines
and on button click - automatically expand the selection from start to end of block

each block is divided by `\n\n`

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  let v = $(tx).val().trim();
    let a = $(tx).prop('selectionStart');
    let b = $(tx).prop('selectionEnd');
    var c = $(tx).val().substring(a, b);
    var res = '<p>' + c + '</p>';
    res = res.replaceAll("\n", "<br>\n");
    v = v.replace(c, res);
    $(tx).val(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='tx' rows = "9">
lorem
ipsum

dolor sit
dolor sit

</textarea>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `replace` call (`v = v.replace(c, res);`) is dangerous, as it depends on value without taking the indices in account. I fixed it too.
2. The idea of my solution is to look for the previous delimiter (`\n\n`) position (or beginnings of text if there isn't) and for the next delimiter position (or end of text if there isn't). Then grab the block, manipulate it, and replace the original block (taking the indices in account) with the manipulated one.

Good Luck.

```js
const replaceBetweenIndices = (origin, startIndex, endIndex, insertion) =>
  origin.substring(0, startIndex) + insertion + origin.substring(endIndex);

$('button').on('click', function(){
  const delimiter = '\n\n';
  const delimiterLength = delimiter.length;
  let originalText = $(tx).val();
  let begSel = parseInt($(tx).prop('selectionStart'));
  let endSel = parseInt($(tx).prop('selectionEnd'));
  var beg, end;
  for(beg = begSel; beg !== 0 && ( beg < delimiterLength || originalText.substring(beg - delimiterLength, beg) !== delimiter ); beg-- );
  for(end = endSel; end !== originalText.length && (end > originalText.length - delimiterLength || originalText.substr(end, delimiterLength) !== delimiter); end++);
  const block = originalText.substring(beg,end);
  manipulatedBlock = `<p>${block.replaceAll("\n", "<br>\n")}</p>`;
  manipulatedText = originalText.substring(0, beg) + manipulatedBlock + originalText.substring(end);
  manipulatedText = manipulatedText.trim();
  $(tx).val(manipulatedText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='tx' rows = "9">
lorem
ipsum

dolor sit
dolor sit

</textarea>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, the concept is strong and safe, I think